# Formula that adds together multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a function or a way of structuring a formula to best find the results of C7, D7 and E7.

These cells need to show the rate x hours for every person on the job.

[image]

What I normally do is (for C7):

```
=(B3xC3)+(B4xC4)+(B5xC5)+(B6xC6)
```

This can become very long and cumbersome when there are lots of people. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in `C7` and drag to `D7:E7`

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B3:$B6,C3:C6)
```

Reference:
[SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294)

Comment: Thank you!!! You have saved me SO much time

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `sumproduct` function (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)).

In your case this should be
`=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B6;C3:C6)`.

Since my excel is not in english the correct syntax may be differnt.

Answer (score 0):

For a single-cell formula, try:

```
=mmult(transpose(B3:B6),C3:E6)
```

[image]